# Gnome terminal: unable to drag tab outside window

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

When I try to drag a tab outside the window panel, I am unable to do so. Dragging inside (rearranging) is possible.

This is so obvious that I am sure I am missing something, since there are even videos on the internet showing that this could be done, but...  I can't.

I am using 17.10, Ubuntu on Xorg, updated from an older distribution.

Comment: Try dragging to a clear area away from the terminal.

Comment: Yes, that's what I do. There is no drag handle at all. I am only allowed to move the tab to the left or to the right, inside the tab button area.

Comment: In Ubuntu 18:
right mouse click on Termianl Tab -> select "Detach Terminal"

Answer (score 6):

Looks like this was disabled because it causes GNOME Terminal to crash. See [bug #769161](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=769161#c13):

> **Christian Persch 2016-08-09 19:38:09 UTC**
>   I've disabled detaching a tab by DND for now until the gtk bug is
>   fixed.